# 2 pod of same deployment restarting at same time

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress

I have 2 pod running of one deployment on kubernetes GKE cluster. I have scale this stateless deployment replicas to 2.

Both replicas almost started at same time both are restating with error code 137 ERROR. To change restart timing i have deleted one pod manually so that RS (replicaset) create new one.

Now again both pods are restarting at same time. Is there any connection between them ?. Both has to work independently.

i have not set a resource limit. In cluster free space upto 3 GB and deployment not taking much memory still getting 137 and restart in pods.

Why both pod restarting at same time that's issue? other all 15 microservices running perfectly.

Comment: check the node logs for OOM, your node may be running out of memory and these two pods may be a lower priority (especially if there is no resource requests/limits defined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error code 137 is [the result](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html#EXITCODESREF) of a `kill -9` (137 = 128 + 9). There can be several reasons:

- As others also pointed out in their answers, this can happen because of out of memory condition. Notice that it could be the application or a process that runs out of memory even though there is no `resources.limits.memory` set. For example, the JVM of a Java application runs out of heap memory.
- Another reason could be that the application/process didn't handle `SIGTERM` (`kill -15`), which was then followed by `SIGKILL` (`kill -9`) to guarantee the shutdown.

It is very likely that both pods get restarted at almost the same time because an error condition is met almost at the same time. For example:

- both pods are started at the same time and get about the same traffic and/or do about the same amount and kind of work and, thus, they run out of memory at almost the same time.
- both pods fail the liveness probe at the same time as the probe's settings in the deployment are the same for both pods.

Check out the events (e.g. `kubectl get events --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp`) - they could show something to help determine the reason for terminating the container(s)/pods.

Comment: thankyou for writing answer it's clear and really helpful also probably I have to dig further & investigate more. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common mistake when pods are defined. If you do not set a CPU and memory limit, there is no upper bound and the pod might take all resources, crash and restart. Those are discussed here [2][3]. You will also see that user “ciokan” [1] fixed his issue by setting the limit.

[1]https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/19825
[2]memory:https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-memory-resource/
[3]CPU:https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-cpu-resource/

Comment: thankyou for writing an answer. still i didn't got answer like why both pod restart at same time.

Answer (score 2):

try to get more logs describing the pod

```
kubectl describe po
```

usually the 137 code means out of memory

did you allocated properly memory for you pods?
 https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-memory-resource/

Comment: thankyou for writing an answer. still i didn't got answer like why both pod restart at same time.